# Bootstrap navbar hamburger icon does not align vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fluent-kit

I use fluent kit with bootstrap 4.1.2.

From the [navbar docs](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/navigation/navbar/) (I want this one because the toggler changes its icon on open / close) I did take the second example, from the #position section. However, the hamburger is not centered vertically. How can I fix it?

Navbar with wrong hamburger:

[image]

I tried removing `padding` but it didn't help and I am stuck.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nespero/fluent-kit@1.3.0/js/fluent-kit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nespero/fluent-kit@1.2.0/css/fluent-kit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark py-2">
  <strong class="navbar-text">
    Navbar position example
  </strong>
  <button class="btn mi navbar-toggler  shadow-none mt-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-position" aria-controls="navbar-position" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navbar submenu</span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-position">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `.btn` class from the `<button>`

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nespero/fluent-kit@1.3.0/js/fluent-kit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nespero/fluent-kit@1.2.0/css/fluent-kit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark py-2">
  <strong class="navbar-text">
    Navbar position example
  </strong>
  <button class="mi navbar-toggler  shadow-none mt-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-position" aria-controls="navbar-position" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navbar submenu</span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-position">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css code in your css file:

```
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler {
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, the `line-height` was an issue, however it comes with a `.btn` class, so the accepted answer is a better approach. Thanks for your input anyway, here's an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css in your css file.

```
.navbar .navbar-toggler {
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
```

Comment: `padding` itself was not enough, but thanks for your input, here's the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use transform:translateY to align

```
.navbar .navbar-toggler {
   transform: translateY(-17%);
 }
```